# what is the limit on size for extensions in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to store some additional info about user in openextension field, so I wander how many information can I put there. Is there some kind of limit on number or size of extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with Microsoft.Graph lib I have found that the limit is 2KB